# get lenght of mp3 in a folder using mutagen

Tags: python, mutagen

I made this code to get the duration of all the mp3 files in a folder, but it gives me an error:

```
import os
from mutagen.mp3 import MP3

path = "D:/FILE/P. F. Ford - A Body on the Beach/"

filenames = next(os.walk(path, topdown=True))
for filename in filenames:
    audio = MP3(filename)
    print(audio.info.length)
```

the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Desktop\.venv\lib\site-packages\mutagen\_util.py", line 251, in _openfile
    fileobj = open(filename, "rb+" if writable else "rb")
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'D:/FILE/P. F. Ford - A Body on the Beach/'
```

i have all the permissions, can you point me to the right path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my question by this code i adapted:

```
import os
from mutagen.mp3 import MP3

path = "D:/FILE/P. F. Ford - A Body on the Beach"


def convert(seconds):
    hours = seconds // 3600
    seconds %= 3600
    mins = seconds // 60
    seconds %= 60
    return(hours, mins, seconds)


for root, dirs, files in os.walk(os.path.abspath(path)):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".mp3"):
            print(os.path.join(root, file))
            audio = MP3(os.path.join(root, file))
            # print(audio.info.length)
            hours, mins, seconds = convert(audio.info.length)
            print(str(int(hours)) + ":" +
                  str(int(mins)) + ":" + str(int(seconds)))
```

Comment: The only question is how can i sum all the durations? to get an total duration.

Comment: just add the lengths together to get a total length

Answer (score 0):

You're error occur due to the wrong filenames when you get **filenames** from your code line

```
filenames = next(os.walk(path, topdown=True))
```

Then you get all types (extensions) of files that are present in that folder.
So, you need to filter these files only ***.mp3** files, and then re-run your code.

Comment: I have added if filename.endswith(".mp3"): , but it gives me an error AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'endswith'

Comment: You need to follow the python instruction, as a filename is a list object and you can't access it like this. You need to convert the list into string then use this function "endswith"